# strtok keeps returning the same word

Tags: c

I am writing the following program that reads some text from a file. Then I want to divide that text into several piece base on spaces. I used `strtok(buffer, " ")` to get the first word on the buffer before the space. That part works fine. However after I used `strtok(NULL, " ")` I get back the same first word. I am expecting to get back the next word. In passing array to the function declared as following `char* buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]`:

```c
int decoder(char *buffer)
{
    int reg_1 = 0;
    int reg_2 = 0;

    char *tok = strtok(buffer, " "); 

    if(strcmp(tok,"ADD") == 0)
    {
        strtok(NULL, " ");
        puts(tok);

        strtok(NULL, " ");
        puts(tok);
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to assign the result of the later calls to strtok().  They should look like:

```
tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
```

Comment: Thank you that was the issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
int decoder(char *buffer)
{
   int reg_1 = 0;
   int reg_2 = 0;

   char *tok = strtok(buffer, " "); 

   if(strcmp(tok,"ADD") == 0)
   {
      puts(tok);
      tok=strtok(NULL, " ");


   }            
}
```

The returned pointer from `strtok()` must be assigned to the `tok`

Comment: The explanation is wrong and the code will not work any better than the code in the question.